# Check if two directories are on the same filesystem in haskell

Tags: linux, macos, haskell, directory, filesystems

If I have two directories `A` and `B` How do I tell if they are on the same filesystem (e.g on same hardrive) in Haskell  on OS X and linux ?

I checked `System.Directory` and `System.FilePath.Posix` which don't seem to have any thing for doing this.

Comment: What do you mean by filesystem here? Something like `ext4` or `zfs` ?

Comment: I mean on two different hard drives for example. The use case is that if they are on different hardrives I want to copy files otherwise I would want to move some files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`getFileStatus`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.0.1/docs/System-Posix-Files.html#v:getFileStatus) and [`deviceID`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.0.1/docs/System-Posix-Files.html#v:deviceID) functions from the unix package should help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to exploit the `stat` utility and write a wrapper for it yourself. `stat` has the ability to give device number for your file. I tested this following code in Linux and it works for different disks (but I'm not sure for Mac OS):

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import System.Process

statDeviceID :: FilePath -> IO String
statDeviceID fp = readProcess "stat" ["--printf=%d", fp] ""
-- for mac which has a different version of stat
-- statDeviceID fp = readProcess "stat" ["-f", "%d", fp] ""

checkSameDevice :: [FilePath] -> IO Bool
checkSameDevice xs = (\x -> all (== head x) x) <$> (sequence $ map statDeviceID xs)

paths = ["/mnt/Books", "/home/sibi"]

main = checkSameDevice paths >>= print
```

In ghci:

```
λ> main
False   -- False since /mnt is a different hard disk
```

Comment: @Bilal you can do the [os checking](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/System-Info.html#v:os) bit by that function, in case you need it.